# Printf Circle by percentage in C without graphics library

Tags: c

I've created a program to print a circle to the console determined by a user given diameter.

Now I want to modify the program to print only a certain percentage of the circle, it should look something like the attached photo.

I'm searching for a solution since nearly 2 hours now and I can't get my head around it. Can somebody pls help me.

Note: It's for an assignment and I'm only allowed to use "simple" C, so no pointers, external libraries and all that stuff

I already have the starting program I wrote:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * @brief Prints the header to the console
 */
void printHeader() {
    printf("Ausgabe Teilaufgabe 5.2.1\n");
}

/**
 * @brief Get the Durchmesser from the user via console input
 * 
 * @return int (Durchmesser)
 */
int getDurchmesser() {
    int d = 0;
    printf("Bitte Durchmesser des Kreises eingeben: ");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    getchar();
    return d;
}

/**
 * @brief Prints a circle out of "*" to the console with a given diameter
 * 
 * @param d (Durchmesser)
 */
void printCircle(int d) {
    for(int i= -d; i < d; i++) {
        for(int j = -d; j < d; j++) {
            if(i*i + j*j < d*d) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Starting point of the program
 * 
 * @return int (Success Code)
 */
int main() {
    printHeader();
    int d = getDurchmesser();
    printCircle(d);
    return 0;
}
```

`

I also have an image of how the final program should look like:
[image: That's how it should look like when finished]

Comment: You need to add additional condotion based on angle of the vector from circle center to current dot. Start by crwating a helper function which gives you the angle of line between 2 points. Google should help you easily.

Comment: Then you need to convert "percentage" to start and end angle of the gap.

Comment: Then just use this in your drawing condition.

Comment: Can you probably give a coding example I can't really figure it out

Comment: `if(isValidDirection(i, j, percentage) && i*i + j*j < d*d) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }`. And then just implement isValidDirection function. Start with something dummy, then work on it until it does the right thing.

Comment: Allocate a 2D matrix of characters, store everything there first, then print. Doing this without trigonometry, just loops, also sounds cumbersome.

Comment: It is explicitly requested to use math, we unfortunately aren't allowed to use an array

Comment: So I'm finally getting the point of the isValidDirection function, I just don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a thing worth to mention about the code: the diameter obtained from the user is used as a radius. But that makes rather little problem as the only difference here is the circle being smaller than expected. In the code below, I'll change the `d` in your the code to `r` to avoid any confusion what it represents.

Now ad rem.

[@hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717300/hyde) made a good point in the comments to the question that, for the "Pac-Man" to "open its mouth", you need to only make that single condition more restrictive. However, I don't quite know how it could be achieved using angles. Therefore, I'll show it without using them.

While we could modify only that one condition, it will be not so intuitive (at least for me). It is because in your code the ordinate (`i`) ranges from `-r` to `r`. In most cases that I've seen the ordinate ranges from `r` to `-r` (the sign of each number is reversed). So at first we would like to change

```c
for(int i= -r; i < r; i++)
```

to

```c
for(int i= r; i > -r; i--)
```

just for the sake of intuitiveness of the condition. Note that I changed not only the signs, but also the inequality kind (from `<` to `>`), and the iteration expression (from `i++` to `i--`).

Now, the [equation of a circle in Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) looks like that (I tried to write it in a mathematical form):

```
(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2
```

where:

- `x` denotes the `x` coordinate of a point within the circle,
- `a` denotes the `x` coordinate of the center of the circle,
- `y` denotes the `y` coordinate of a point within the circle,
- `b` denotes the `y` coordinate of the center of the circle,
- `r` denotes the radius of the circle.

Your code already makes use of this equation in the following way:

```c
if(i*i + j*j < r*r)
```

Of course, this is an inequality, because we want to print the disk, not just the circle (you can try to change the `<` to `==` and see what will happen).

The "Pac-Man" in the expected output has its mouth open in the [third quadrant of the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Quadrants_and_octants). This means that both the abscissa and the ordinate are negative. That leads us to tell the code: "Don't show anything in the third quadrant of the plane". This, in turn, leads to the following change in the condition:

```c
if(i*i + j*j < r*r && !(j < 0 && i < 0))
```

But, we don't want the "whole quadrant" to be empty, we want only the part representing the "mouth". As I assume from the expected output, the bottom line of the "Pac-Man"'s "mouth" is determined by a line represented by the equation `y = x` (mathematical notation). Since in the code `y` is named `i`, and `x` is named `j`, the equation becomes `i = j` (mathematical notation). Then, since the mouth is open up the line, we want rather an inequality here: `i > j` (mathematical notation. `i >= j` would also be good in this particular case). This leads us to tell the code: "Don't print anything in the third quadrant of the plane, but  only above the line represented by `i = j`". This, in turn, leads to the following change in the condition:

```c
if(i*i + j*j < r*r && !(j < 0 && i < 0 && i > j))
```

So, the whole function `printCircle` would look like this:

```c
void printCircle(int r) {
    for(int i= r; i > -r; i--) {
        for(int j = -r; j < r; j++) {
            if(i*i + j*j < r*r && !(j < 0 && i < 0 && i > j)) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Now, the ouput of the code is more or less the same as the expected output.